# Is it a good idea to use nested function arrays?

Tags: c++

I need a menu. At first I used monstrous if-else cascades, here's what it looked like (don't wonder about weird `while(selection > x)` loops, it's just a bizarre way to get input):

```
int main() {
    ...
    do {
        std::cout << "\nMENU\n";
        std::cout << "The container is " << (list.empty() ? "empty.\n" : "not empty.\n");
        std::cout << "Enter:\n1 to edit the container\n2 to execute functions on it\n0 to stop program\n";
        while((selection = intInput()) > 2)
            std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
        if(selection == 1) {
            std::cout << "\nEnter:\n1 to print container\n2 to empty container\n";
            std::cout << "3 to add elements from file\n4 to add elements from console\n0 to return to menu\n";
            while((selection = intInput()) > 4)
                std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
            if(selection == 1) {
                ...
            }
            else if(selection == 2) {
                list.clear();
                if(list.empty()) std::cout << "Successfully erased container.\n";
            }
            else if(selection == 3) {
                fileInput(list);
                std::cout << "Successfully added elements from file.\n";
            }
            else if(selection == 4) {
                consoleInput(list);
                std::cout << "Successfully added elements from console.\n";
            }
        }
        else if(selection == 2) {
            std::cout << "\nFUNCTION LIST\n";
            std::cout << "1. Find students with average mark more than K.\n";
            std::cout << "2. Find students with highest average mark per group (could be several).\n";
            std::cout << "3. Sort students by groups.\n";
            std::cout << "Enter function number:\n";
            while((selection = intInput()) > 3)
                std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
            std::cout << "\nEnter:\n1 to print result in file\n2 to print in console only\n0 to return to menu\n";
            while((selectionFile = intInput()) > 2)
                std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            if(selectionFile == 1)
                fileOutput(fileO);
            if(selection == 1) {
                ...
                std::cout << "\nSuccessfully finished.\n";
            }
            else if(selection == 2) {
                ...
                std::cout << "\nSuccessfully finished.\n";
            }
            else if(selection == 3) {
                ...
                std::cout << "\nSuccessfully finished.\n";
            }
        }
        if(selection == 0) {
            std::cout << "\nEnter:\n1 to return to menu\n0 to stop program\n";
            while((selection = intInput()) > 1)
                std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
        }
    } while (selection != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

But this is barely readable. Then someone suggested me an idea to make it through arrays, since all my inputs are integers from 0 to n. I understood it as arrays of functions. And now it looks like this (just creating the arrays):

```
std::array <std::function < void(std::vector <std::string>) >, 2> ChoiceMain = {Edit, Func};
        std::array <std::function < void(std::vector <std::string>) >, 4> ChoiceEdit1 = {Print, AddFromFile, AddFromConsole, Empty};
            std::array <std::function < void(std::vector <std::string>) >, 2> ChoicePrint11 = {PrintConsole, PrintFile};
        std::array <std::function < void(std::vector <std::string>) >, 3> ChoiceFunc2 = {Func1, Func2, Func3};
```

Which is, well... still barely readable. It should work like this: we have bridge functions, which just print information for user, take the variable and call function from corresponding array, like if we call function Edit, it takes `i` and calls `ChoiceEdit[i]`; and we have final functions that do stuff.
Is it a right way to create a menu?

Comment: Your menu system could possibly benefit from using a `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: [`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) those `std::array <std::function < void(std::vector <std::string>) >, 2>`'s, and I think that actually looks pretty dang clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a couple of meaningful names

```
using MenuFunction = std::function<void(std::vector<std::string>)>;
template<int Items>
using Menu = std::array<MenuFunction, Items>;
```

and you get

```
Menu<2> ChoiceMain = {Edit, Func};
Menu<4> ChoiceEdit1 = {Print, AddFromFile, AddFromConsole, Empty};
Menu<2> ChoicePrint11 = {PrintConsole, PrintFile};
Menu<3> ChoiceFunc2 = {Func1, Func2, Func3};
```

which is far from unredable.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create a pointer to methods with std::map:

The elements (or actions in the FSM) to execute:

```
typedef enum {
    ACTION1,
    ACTION2,
    ACTION3
} action_t;
```

The declaration of the methods:

`action_t Foo::bar()`

The aliasses:

```
typedef action_t (Foo::*actionsPtr_t)(void);
typedef std::map<action_t, actionsPtr_t> stateFuncMap_t;
```

The mapping:

```
stateFuncMap_t mapping;

mapping[ACTION1] = &Foo::bar;
mapping[ACTION2] = &Foo::bar2;
mapping[ACTION3] = &Foo::bar3;
```

The way to execute it:

```
Foo fsm;
action_t nextAction;

nextAction = (fsm.*(mapping[ACTION1]))();
nextAction = (fsm.*(mapping[nextAction]))();
```

Where each method returns the next method to execute.

Comment: This is great, by the way, do you need to use `typedef enum` in C++? You need it in C to write `action_t var` instead of `enum action_t var`, but it seems that in C++ it is the same as default enum.

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky yes, you are right, I'm very influenced by C